# Adding a node to a BST of strings

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

This is for a school assignment. I get a seg fault when I try to add a new node to a BST. I think it may have something to do with how I've allocated the memory, but I can't figure out how to fix the issue.

Struct code:

```
struct tnode {
  char* data;
  struct tnode* left;
  struct tnode* right;
};

typedef struct tnode Tnode;
```

Add node function:

```
Tnode* add_tnode(Tnode* current_tnode, char* value) {
  if (current_tnode == NULL) {
    malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    current_tnode->data = value;
    current_tnode->left = NULL;
    current_tnode->right = NULL;
    return current_tnode;
      }
  else {
    if (strcmp(current_tnode->data, value) <= 0) {
      add_tnode(current_tnode->left, value);
      return current_tnode->left;
      }
    else {
      add_tnode(current_tnode->right, value);
      return current_tnode->right;
      }
  }
}
```

Main program to test the function:

```
int main() {
  Tnode* new_node =  (Tnode*)malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
  char* data1 = "Hello";
  char* data2 = "Goodbye";
  char* data3 = "Hi";
  char* data4 = "Bye";
  char* data5 = "Hey";

  add_tnode(new_node, data1);
  add_tnode(new_node, data2);
  add_tnode(new_node, data3);
  add_tnode(new_node, data4);
  add_tnode(new_node, data5);

  return 0;
}
```

This is the error I receive when I backtrace the segmentation fault:

```
#0  0x0000003458478350 in strcmp () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000004005be in add_tnode (current_tnode=0x601010, 
    value=0x400708 "Hello") at tree.c:16
#2  0x0000000000400523 in main () at treetest.c:12
```

I'm thinking that when strcmp() tries to find the string stored in the node, it can't find it. Any help or tips would be very appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: Yes that is how I got a backtrace to my seg fault.

Comment: well, next time check the generated/altered data structures and check what exactly happens..

Answer (score 1):

The line (in `add_tnode`)

```
malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
```

should be

```
current_tnode = malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
```

You're currently immediately discarding the return value from `malloc`, meaning that the next line of code dereferences a NULL pointer, causing your seg fault.

You also need to initialise the members of `new_node` in `main`, either explicitly or by allocating using `calloc`.  And, as noted by Karoly Horvath, use the return values from `add_tnode`

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover a second problem.  I think this'll be the one you've been seeing.  (The initial problem I pointer out is valid; just not the particular bug that's currently tripping you up)

Comment: Okay I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 1):

another problem:

`add_tnode` returns the address of the newly allocated node, but you never use it.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access to the field "data", of "new_node",

but "new_node" is not initialized with a data value.

you need to move these lines out of the if clause:

```
 current_tnode->data = value;
current_tnode->left = NULL;
current_tnode->right = NULL;
```

Good luck.